# Slow Read Speeds with new SSD In Mac Pro

Tags: ssd, windows-10

I thought I would try and reinvigorate my old mac pro 1,1 desktop.

Made in about 2006, it's fairly old hardware, but I thought a new SSD might give it a new lease of life.

I put in a 500GB Samsung EVO 850, installed Windows 10, and after running HD Tune, reports an average read speed of just 180MB/Sec.

Comparing this to others with the same disk, I see that they are able to get more than twice this speed without breaking a sweat.

Am I being constrained by my old hardware (disk controller / small data bus)? Or is there something that can be done to speed it up?

Answer (score 2):

[Your Mac Pro uses SATA-300](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Pro#Hard_drives), and that's bottlenecking you. You want to use a modern sata 3 port - and well, that's not something you can easily upgrade

This seems slowish, but fairly consistent with the speeds listed [in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/545157/highest-effective-transfer-rate-on-sata-ii).

There's probably other bottlenecks with hardware that old, but you're probably getting better performance than with the old drive. I do suspect a pci-e/sata 3.0 card or a suitable raid controller might let you get more out of your SSD, but I've got no real, direct experience with those.

Comment: Yes, I think Mac Pro 1,1's have SATA 2 ports, but these are supposed to go up to 300MB/Sec

Comment: 300MB/sec is the theoretical maximum. In practice you'll get a smidge over 250MB/sec under ideal conditions and only if *nothing else is accessing the disk at the same time*. Plus the major advantage of SSDs isn't sequential transfer rate anyway, it's the random speeds.

Comment: I get around 250 read, 270 write on a Mac Pro 5,1 with SATA II, so that sounds about right. 180 does seem a bit slow, but the 1,1 has much slower architecture throughout, so I'd call it 'about OK'

Comment: heh. *Completely* missed that this was a desktop. And yeah, those are best case speeds.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling AHCI (http://www.bladedmink.com/windows-8-ahci-support-on-macbook-pro/) upped the average speed from 180MB/Sec to 225MB/Sec.

Note the following steps are actually for a Macbook Pro (laptop), but worked a charm on my Mac Pro (desktop).

Edit:

Crucial steps from bladedmink.com incase it ever disappears - Note, read through all these steps before actually performing them.

- Login to Windows
- Launch Regedit
- Find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\storahci\`

  - Edit the `ErrorControl` Data value from `3` to `0`.
- Find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\storahci\StartOverride\`

  - Edit the `0` Data value from `3` to `0`.
- Shutdown and boot into OS X
- Download and run https://www.bladedmink.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/AHCI_Enabler.zip on the NTFS drive.
- Shutdown and boot into Windows
- Prey you don't get a BSOD.

I am using the Standard Microsoft AHCI controller driver.

I tried to to install the Intel Matrix AHCI drivers, but they actually ran a few percent slower. When I tried to uninstall (and checked the 'also delete drivers') from Device Manager I got a boot loop and had to install windows from scratch.

Comment: ah hah! Could you have some of that information in your answer? It would be useful should the link go down

Comment: Sure thing - I didn't even realise it wasn't running in AHCI mode until I ran the 'AS SSD' benchmark tool.

Answer (score 0):

I can hit 828.06/682.93 MBs with apple ssd SMO128G installed on pcie slot 4th set as 4 lanes, MP 1,1/2,1 doesn't reconize M.2 nvme ssd. So i was using M.2 pcie adapter with 2nd adapter as bridge(apple ssd to m.2 adapter).by doing this i was able to install el capitan on pcie ssd and boot from it even my MP 2,1 reconized as external storage. With this setup i was  able to take advantages of pcie lane's speed. Booted into desktop in 9s from the chime sound to complete boot.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed, personal story. However, this does not answer the question. Do you have any ideas on how OP can speed up their hard drive?